# Can't fix this error when running my code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I get this error when I'm trying to run my code:

"error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
9 |     int *a = GC::allocate(sizeof(int));"

I am trying to make a function that acts as a garbage collector and right now am first trying to make the dynamical allocation for pointers (since the pointers are going to point to their respective chunk/block of memory, allocated from the GC class).

main.cpp:

```
int *a = GC::allocate(sizeof(int));
*a = 5;
cout << a << " " << *a << endl;
```

GC.cc:

```
void* GC::allocate(size_t size)
{
    Chunk();
    bool flag = 1;
    size_t i, j, l;
    for(i = 0; i < SHEET_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(sheets2[i] == 0)
        {
            for(j = i; j < i+size; j++)
            {
                if(sheets2[j] != 0)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag)
            {
                for(l = i;l < j;l++)
                {
                    sheets2[l] = 1;
                }
                chunk = &sheet[i];
                chunks.push_back(Chunk(chunk, size, 1));
                chunks_count++;
                return chunk;
            }
        }
    }
    return (char*)"ERROR";
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to question: `(char*)"ERROR"` will cause undefined behavior if you ever try to access it through e.g. an `int` pointer or try to write to it. There is also no way to check for whether the function returned it. Just return `nullptr` on error or throw an exception, so that the caller can check for it.

Comment: In standard C++, unlike C, there is no implicit conversion of a `void *` to any other pointer type  (the reverse, converting any pointer type (other than a pointer to a function or a pointer to member) to `void *` is permitted, which is why the implementation of `GC::allocate()` compiles).   If you need such a conversion, you need to explicitly force the compiler to allow the conversion, such as `int *a = (int *)GC::allocate(sizeof(int))`  (C cast) or, preferable in C++, `int *a = static_cast<int *>(GC::allocate(sizeof(int)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly cast the return value:

```cpp
int *a = (int*) GC::allocate(sizeof(int));
```